# pwilcox takes long time when sample size is large in r

Tags: r, pairwise.wilcox.test

I have very large sample sizes. For example, pwilcox(6000, 36, 17000). The problem is that, it takes a lot of time on r to return the p-value. How can I make it fast?

Comment: Can [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction) help?

Comment: @RuiBarradas This is the main formula that wilcox.test is using internally.